# Coroutine Error - "inferred type is Job but CompletableJob was expected"

Tags: android, coroutine

I have a long running coroutine.  I am trying to hold onto the thread, so it can be cancelled upon user demand.  This was working quite well before, but since I just switched from version 1.1.1 to 1.3.0, I'm now getting this compilation error: "inferred type is Job but CompletableJob was expected".  However, CompletableJob doesn't appear to be a class type in Coroutines?

```
class DashboardPresenter(private val view: DashboardContract.View) : DashboardContract.Presenter {
  private var thread = Job()
  private var duration: Int = ConfigData.refresh * 1000

  private fun loadDataRefresher() {
    counter++
    val next = if (running) ", next in ${ConfigData.refresh} seconds" else ""
    Timber.d("********* Dashboard Refresh #${counter} $next ************")
    thread = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        if (running) {
            updateUi(area)
            delay(duration.toLong())
            loadDataRefresher()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like by default when we declare a `Job`, we are getting a `CompleteableJob` instead of `Job` and hence the error. 
So, when declaring the `job`, if we define the `type` explicitly, the error is gone.

In the above case: 
`private var thread: Job = Job()` this will work.

Please add if anything is missing.